# Connecting Oracle 11g in Powerplay Transformer 7.3 via ODBC

Tags: oracle, cognos, transformer-model

I am using Cognos Powerplay Transformer 7.3 and wants to connect Oracle 11g through ODBC, but i can not see the ODBC as a data source options, the options i see are :
- Impromptu Query Definition
- Delimited-field text with column titles
- Delimeted-field text
- dBase tabel
etc.

Answer (score 0):

In that version of Transformer, you need to create an IQD file. To create an IQD file you need to create a report in Impromptu (another client application) then save your report as an IQD file.

If you are comfortable hacking, you can actually create an IQD file from a blank text file and paste your Oracle SQL straight in.

Do you have Impromptu installed? Have you created a DSN to Oracle and tested it?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. No, Impromptu is not installed and i am looking forward to install it and test the connection and then create the file.